# When to fetch RemoteConfig for Firebase while Executing A/B Testing

Tags: android, firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I am trying to implement A/B testing on my android app using Firebase RemoteConfig. My targeted audience is dependent on following two Firebase events.

1) First_Open : (Fired automatically by Firebase when first launch).
2) Some_Custom_Event : (Fired on the second activity/screen).

So if i will fetch the remote config on the launch of the app, i dont think will get the desired velues based on the targeted audience params of A\B testing because the second event had not yet been fired for that user.

Please suggest whether i wait for the second event to fire and then do the fetch or is there any other better approach of achieving the same ?

Thanks.